# Python return False if list is empty

Tags: python

In one coding example i saw the following code snippet that returns **True** if the list is empty and **False** if not

```
return a == []
```

the reason for that is to avoid writing

```
if a:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

In a real example with multiple thousands of entries, is there any speed difference i should be aware of?

Comment: `x == []` seems to short circuit (CPython 3), so the performance of both approaches should be O(1), and multiple thousands of entries vs. one or two entries should not matter.

Comment: That second snippet doesn't match your described logic, I think `True` and `False` are switched around. Your intent could just be written `not bool(a)` by the way.

Comment: @detly or even `not a`

Comment: Never mind the speed, which is the easiest to understand and maintain?

Comment: Use Python's truthiness, where `[]` tests as false, and non-empty lists test as true. No need to get fancy because the whole point of this truthiness approach *is* to be able to use list lengths equivalent to boolean values.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, i agree with all of you, i would definitely go for the more pythonic way, it was just that i saw this snippet.@Jens thanks for the reminder that the test [] should be false!

Comment: Are you asking if there will be a speed difference between running the two functions that use those methods?

Comment: I don't think that the performance is different. But the last piece of code is equivalent to `return not a` or `return not bool(a)`; wich is a lot shorter.

Comment: Like CodingLambda suggestions too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking which method would faster if put in a function(hence the `return`'s), then I used the `timeit` module to do a little testing. I put each method in a function, and then ran the program to see which function ran faster. Here is the program:

```
import timeit

def is_empty2():
    a = []
    if a:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_empty1():
    a = []
    return a == []


print("Time for method 2:")
print(timeit.timeit(is_empty2))
print("")
print("Time for method 1:")
print(timeit.timeit(is_empty1))
```

I ran the program five times, each time recording the speed for each function. After getting an average for each time, here is what I came up with:

```
method one speed(milliseconds): 0.2571859563796641
-----------------------------   ------------------
method two speed(milliseconds): 0.2679253742685615
```

At least from my testing above, the first method you described in your question was *slightly* faster than the second method. Of course those numbers above could drastically change depending on what exactly is inside those two functions.

I agree however, with what Cdarke said in the comments. Go with the one that is the most clear and concise. Don't go with one option solely based upon its speed. in the words of Guido van Rosom: *Readability counts*.

Answer (score 11):

No. There is no speed difference in either case. Since in both cases the `length` of the list is checked first.
In the first case, the `len` of `a` is compared with the `len` of `[]` before any further comparison. Most times the `len` should differ, so the test just returns immediately.

But the more pythonic way would be to just `return not a` or convert it using `bool` and then return it:

```
return not a

# or 

return not bool(a)
```